# Why BJT thermal voltage can be not equal to kT/q in SPICE3

Tags: bjt, simulation, semiconductors, spice, theory

In SPICE, apart from effects such as basewidth modulation and base-collector leakage the collector current is given by the expression (according to the original SPICE2 PhD work)

[image: IcExpression]

But actually, according to the SPICE3 source code two model parameters - Nf and Nr, forward and reverse current emission coefficients, modify the thermal voltage Vt as so:

[image: IcExpressionNfNr]

Pretty much anywhere where Vbe is divided by Vt, Vt is multiplied Nf, and where Vbc is divided by Vt, Vt is multiplied by Nr. This "rule" applies as well, for example, for the Qb term Q2:

[image: Q2Expression]

My question is, do transistors in real life behave like this as well, and what are the physical reasons for these Nf and Nr coefficients? Or are these just some empirical model parameters without any physical causes whatsoever? I am trying to calculate the output current of an analog exponential coverter, so the actual value Vbe is divided by is very important to me.

Comment: But for the small-signal BJT's NF and NR is equal to 1.

Comment: @G36 Not small-signal matched BJT pairs are sometimes used for cost reasons, such as BC847BS dual matched transistor pair. For it NF is set at 0.9932 in SPICE model included with Multisim, and in the model provided by Nexperia it is essentially changed by the area factor.

Comment: @sx107 I think you are talking about the [emission coefficient or ideality factor](Shockley diode equation). For details, I'd refer you to *"Radioactive and Photoelectric pn Junction Power Sources,"* W. G. Pfann & W. Van Roosbroeck, Journal of Applied Physics 25, 1422 (1954); doi: 10.1063/1.1721579.

Comment: @jonk Thank you, for some reason I thought these are not the same. I'll take a look at the article you've cited, though, since I am still interested in what exactly are the reasons for non-ideality.

Comment: @sx107 The authors write, *"Such behavior may be associated with comparatively gradual transition from n- to p-type, with appreciable increases in local conductivity by carrier injection, with junction non-uniformity, and with non-uniform junction bias."* Look in and around that area, to start. I've looked at it as a ***modeling parameter***, though. Used to perform a "best fit" over the range that designers felt were most appropriate for the device.

Comment: @sx107 You might also look at *"Exact Analytical Solution of the Diode Ideality Factor of a pn Junction Device Using Lambert W-function Model,"* Bayhan & Kavasoglu, 2006.

Comment: @jonk Wow, thank you very much for the last reference, that article is incredible!

Comment: @sx107 My pleasure. And thanks for the kind words!

Comment: Section 1.1.2 and Figure 1.4 of [Semiconductor Device Modeling with SPICE](https://books.google.com/books/about/Semiconductor_Device_Modeling_with_SPICE.html?id=_QZTAAAAMAAJ) explain that N (forward) changes between different current levels.  It's greater than 1 on the low-end due to generation-recombination current being significant, and then when it gets swamped out under higher bias, the N approaches 1.  It's therefore impossible to accurately model a real diode under all conditions using the simple equation.  You would require a subcircuit of some sort to do it.

Comment: @SteKulov still can't find a pdf for that book, unfortunately and buying is not an option for me at the moment (Russia-Ukraine stuff). But wait, you are saying that it is greater than 1, while in most transistor models it is set if not to 1, then to a value LESS than 1?

Comment: @SteKulov so essentially most of the effect is due to non-ideal currents like dark current?

Comment: @sx107 It's expected to be 1 or larger. If it is less than 1, it should be very very close to 1. And in that case, it's just because it "models better" that way over the intended range. As SteKulov points up, the reality of these devices is that they are like "multiple devices" piled up on each other. Just as the sum of multiple exponential curves cannot be represented as a single exponential curve, no matter how hard you try, you still can at least try to use a single *approximating* exponential that is "close enough."

Comment: Here are some rough scans ([one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXdCL.jpg) and [two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkzUl.jpg)).  Section 1.1.2a explains the carrier generation-recombination effect.  Figure 1-4 shows how the real curves don't match the ideal equation and identifies the different forward conducting regions.

Comment: @jonk So n<1 are purely empirical?

Comment: @SteKulov Thank you for the scans! Exactly what I was looking for. The theory here is pretty much applicable to transistors as well since a transistor is essentially two pn junctions, right?

Comment: @sx107 If I saw one that was much less than 1, and *not* very close to 1, then I'd assume that someone discovered something new about the universe or else created a very, very, very strange device. Either way, I'd investigate it because whatever the reason, it would have to be an educational one. And yes, any value less than 1, but very close to 1, is just trying very hard to "fit" to the average of observation. They could just fit the case exactly 1, but then it would be to one side of the behavior. If you are going to be wrong, then be wrong with the least deviations around it.

Comment: @jonk Thank you very much, got it.

Comment: @sx107 Yes, at least for the B-E junction it's the same.  However, I don't know what effect the much lighter doping concentration of the B-C junction has on the generation-recombination stuff.  As for N's less than one, the model parameters are usually found by curve fitting actual measurements.  Sometimes the best curve that's found mismatches the physical nature of the parameters.  For example you can look at M (grading coefficient).  Supposed to be between 0.333 and 0.5 but you'll see it commonly outside this range because it gave the model designer the closest matched capacitance curve.